# token not being sent in pre-flight request Ionic2

Tags: django, angular, ionic2, django-rest-framework, cors

I am working on an app in Ionic 2 using DRF as API service. For authentication purpose I am using JWT. I am sending auth token with each request as `Authorization: jwt [token]`. In Postman, API is working fine.

Now when I am testing it in browser it is not working and I figured out that it is probably not working because the JWT auth token is not being sent in the `OPTIONS` request as a pre-flight. So how do I tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that the `OPTIONS` api was not readable without the Authorization token so we added the `readonly` Auth level for the `OPTIONS` and GET api.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ionic latest versions if you are using `ionic serve` commnad then  you must have to use Proxies to prevent Preflight and CORS Issues,

First add API path and URL in `ionic.config.json` file like

```
{
  "name": "APP-NAME",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://example.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, while calling your API from `http` use the `/api` URL instead of the `http://example.com/api` like,

```
....
    this.http.post('/api', data, {headers:headers}).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    }, err=>{
      console.log("Error!:", err.json());
    });
....
```

After making the above changes you must rerun command `ionic serve`.

Still, if you are getting issues then refer [Handling CORS Issues In Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) and https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

In CORS preflight OPTIONS response Cross-Origin-Allow-Headers should match that of the request.

```
Cross-Origin-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```